# Determine whether $U + W$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $U, W$ be 2 subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and consider the subset of $V$ defined by $U + W = \{u + w |u \in U, w \in W \}$. Determine whether $U + W$ is a subspace of $V$
>
> $u, w$ denote vectors

We know that $\vec{0} \in U + W$, since $\vec{0} \in U, W$

Let $x = u_1 + w_1, y = u_2 + w_2, u, y \in U + W$, it follows that $x + y = (u_1 + u_2) + (w_1 + w_2)$. From defintion of $U, W$, it follows that $x + y \in U + W$

Let $x = u_1 + w_1$, consider a scalar $c$, $cx = cu_1 + cu_2$, by definition of $U, W$, it follows that $cx = cu_1 + cu_2 \in U + W$

So it passes the subspace test and thus is a subspace of $V$?

Comment: Yes, everything follows from definition of subspace.

Answer (score 0):

$F+G:=\{t+r: t\in F, r \in G\}$ is always a subspace if F and G are subspaces of E, and is the minimal subspace that contains F and G

As we are in a vectorial space, the axioms of $E$ hold in $F, G$ and we have only to check the next two conditions:

1.- $(\forall v, w \in F+G)(v+w\in F+G)$

$$
v+w=(t+r)+(t'+r')=(t+t')+(r+r') = t''+r'' \text{ and by definition } t''+r'' \in F+G, t,t',t''\in F, r,r',r''\in G \Rightarrow v+w \in F+G
$$

2.- $(\forall \lambda \in K)(\forall v \in F+G)( \lambda v \in F+G)$

$$
\lambda v = \lambda(t+r) = \lambda t + \lambda r \text{ and by definition } \lambda t + \lambda r  \in F+G, t \in F, r \in G \Rightarrow \lambda v \in F+G
$$

So yes, you're right.